# How to use Viewbox to show server-generated SVG?

Tags: svg

My application is to show part of a SVG generated in the server side. The way I get the SVG is through

```
fetch("https://xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx/mychart.svg")
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
document.getElementById('sampleImg').src = imageUrl;});
```

in html `<img id="sampleImg" viewbox="100 100 600 400">`

My question is that I can show the whole SVG in `<img>`, but it seems like viewbox `min-x, min-y` seem not working properly. I wonder if this is the correct way of doing it. If not, would you please show me a correct example?

thank you.

**One Solution**
I found the solution. but any other better solutions are more than welcome. const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob) + "#svgView(viewBox(225,0,255,184))"

Comment: I found the solution. but any other better solutions are more than welcome.

    const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob) + "#svgView(viewBox(225,0,255,184))";

Comment: add the update into the question by editing it